# Ruby Savon Parse Additional Option

Tags: ruby, savon

I use Savon with SOAP requests.
I try to send structure below with USD currency:

```
'urn2:Amt' => {
  'urn2:InstdAmt Ccy="USD"' => 1.00
},
```

Unfortunately SAVON misinterprets this and send something like this

```
<urn2:Amt><urn2:InstdAmt Ccy="USD">1.0</urn2:InstdAmt>Ccy="USD"&gt;</urn2:Amt>
```

I'm making a mistake somewhere, the correct structure should look like this:

```
<urn2:Amt>
  <urn2:InstdAmt Ccy="USD">1.00</urn2:InstdAmt>
</urn2:Amt>
```

Can you give me a hint?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Savon uses [`gyoku`](https://github.com/savonrb/gyoku) for xml generation so you can leverage that syntax to generate the xml you are looking for.

Per [Explicit XML Attributes](https://github.com/savonrb/gyoku#explicit-xml-attributes) in the docs:

> In addition to using the `:attributes!` key, you may also specify attributes through keys beginning with an "@" sign. Since you'll need to set the attribute within the hash containing the node's contents, a `:content!` key can be used to explicity set the content of the node. The `:content!` value may be a String, Hash, or Array.

So in your example

```
client = Savon::Client.new(endpoint: 'http://example.com', namespace: 'http://v1.example.com') 
locals = {message: {"Amt"=>{"InstdAmt"=>{"@Ccy"=>"USD", :content!=>1.0}}}}
Savon::Builder.new('example',c.wsdl,c.globals,locals).build_document
```

This will generate the following xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<env:Envelope xmlns:env="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:wsdl="http://v1.example.com" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
   <env:Body>
      <wsdl:example>
         <Amt>
            <InstdAmt Ccy="USD">1.0</InstdAmt>
         </Amt>
      </wsdl:example>
   </env:Body>
</env:Envelope>
```

Comment: Not working for me. Nothing happen. I can manage attribute like that:

"Amt" => {
  "InstdAmt" => {
    "@Ccy" : "USD"
  }
}

But i have some trouble with add amount value to `InstdAmt`

Comment: Thank you :)  that's what I was missing -> `:content!`